# ValueError: unsupported format character '{' (0x7b) in defining dictionary

Tags: python

I'm writing some code for web development using Google Python Appengine. In my code I have to concatenate strings using % and dictionary Here's the code I've written.

```
def print_form(self, unameError='', passwdError='', verpasswdError='', emailError='', unameValue='', emailValue='' ):
    self.response.out.write( form3 % {  "unameError"    : unameError, 
                                        "passwdError"   : passwdError, 
                                        "verpasswdError": verpasswdError, 
                                        "emailError"    : emailError, 
                                        "unameValue"    : unameValue,  
                                        "emailValue"    : emailValue
                                     }  
                            )
```

For this code, I'm receiving this error from server :

> web-app-local-directory-path/main.py", line 139, in print_form
>       "emailValue"  : emailValue ValueError: unsupported format character '{' (0x7b) at index 218

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong in this code. I've defined a valid dictionary and there seem to be no problem with it according to me.

Somebody please help me on this.

Regards
Vaid, Abhishek

Comment: What string is print_form being called with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you may have the sequence "%{" in the value of `form3`.

Comment: Actually, my mistake was that I was using %{identifier}s instead of %(identifier)s ... Thanks everyone for their help.